# How to manage Folder specific Permission in TFS?

Tags: git, tfs

Your quick help will be highly appreciated...

I have created a project in TFS 2018, In this project we have multiple folders as every folder is related a to a component (Each component will have separate code skeleton as well) in the application.

Every folder will have their separate admin... an admin of a folder (e.g. admin of 'Gate' folder should not be able to change anything in another folder except gate.)

In Add. to admin, users also restricted to particular/allowed folder. How we can manage such folder specific restrictions within a project???

A screenshot for project directory is [Image for Sample Project Dir.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BEYB.jpg)attached.

Answer (score 1):

TFS with GIT does not support permissions for folders. I think, you may consider to use TFVC as version control or to use a separate git repo for each component (TFS supports multiple git repo in one team project [Exercise 7: Managing repositories](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/git/)).

Answer (score 1):

For TFVC it's available, however there is some differences between TFVC and Git.

TFVC and Git have different security models so it's not possible to lock down a specific path in a Git repo like you do in TFVC. With Git repos in TFS you could either:

1. Apply [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?toc=/vsts/git/toc.json&bc=/vsts/git/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=vsts) to a branch
2. Or, if you want to lock down changes to a specific path in a branch is to switch on [branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies?view=vsts) and use the [code reviewer policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies?view=vsts#automatically-include-code-reviewers) to require a reviewer to approve changes in a specific path of your code base.

According to your code, seems you are using git as your source control, you may have to use above solution as workaround.